# How to set __referrer of a form to another action and controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have two domain models, called `Foo` and `Bar`. For both of them, I have a controller with the default CRUD operations. In the `displayAction` of `Foo`s, there is a form to create a new `Bar` (rendered using a partial). Thanks to Helmut Hummels Extension "[typoscript_rendering](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typoscript_rendering)" I can easily submit that form to the `BarController` with AJAX.

However, if validation fails for the created `Bar`-object, the `newAction` of the `BarController` should be called, so the user can fix the problems.

But instead, the `displayAction` of the `FooController` is called. This happens, because Fluid automatically inserts the currently executed action as referrer into the form:

```
<input name="tx_myextension_display[__referrer][@extension]"  value="MyExtension"   type="hidden">
<input name="tx_myextension_display[__referrer][@vendor]"     value="MyVendor"      type="hidden">
<input name="tx_myextension_display[__referrer][@controller]" value="FooController" type="hidden">
<input name="tx_myextension_display[__referrer][@action]"     value="display"       type="hidden">
```

Is there any hack-free way to change the __referrer to the `newAction` of the `BarController`?

**Edit**: As requested, the form as it is in fluid. Unnecessary markup is removed, variable names are anonymized and it is rendered as part of the `displayAction` of the `FooController`:

```
{namespace helhum=Helhum\TyposcriptRendering\ViewHelpers}

<f:form
    name="bar"
    object="{MyBar}"
    action="create"
    controller="Bar"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    additionalAttributes="{data-ajax-uri: '{helhum:uri.ajaxAction(action: \\'create\\', controller: \\'Bar\\')}'}"
>
    <f:form.textarea property="b"/>
    <f:form.submit value="Submit"/>
</f:form>
```

It is just a 08/15-form.

If I submit it with invalid data, I am forwarded to the `display`-Action of the `FooController`, instead of the `new`-Action of the `BarController`. I guess that makes sense, as long as the form is not submitted by AJAX.

Comment: show us definition of the form that you've put in fluid

Answer (score 2):

I've found a "solution" that is still hacky, because it is susceptible to the open base class problem.

It works by overriding the method `errorAction`, because it is called if a validation error occurs. It also does the redirecting to the referring controller.

My override looks like this:

```
/**
 * If an error occurred while creating a new Bar with an
 * AJAX request, redirect to the new action of this controller.
 */
public function errorAction() {
    if ('createByAjaxAction' === $this->actionMethodName) {
        $this->clearCacheOnError();
        $this->addErrorFlashMessage();
        $this->forward('new');
    }
    else {
        parent::errorAction();
    }
}

/*
 * If an error occurred during this request, this adds
 * a flash message describing the error to the flash
 * message container.
 * @TODO Remove after upgrade to 7.x
 * @return void
 */
protected function addErrorFlashMessage() {
    $errorFlashMessage = $this->getErrorFlashMessage();
    if ($errorFlashMessage !== FALSE) {
        $this->addFlashMessage($errorFlashMessage, '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR);
    }
}

/**
 * Create action that is supposed to be used by AJAX.
 * @param \MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Bar
 */
public function createByAjaxAction($bar) {
    $this->forward('create');
}

/**
 * Normal create action.
 * @param \MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Bar
 */
public function createAction($bar) {
    // Normal entity creation stuff
}
```

My problem with this approach is this: If the original `errorAction` of the `ActionController` from extbase changes in the future (as it does in 7.x, see [this change](https://review.typo3.org/#/c/26944/6) for example), this code will happily break. Same thing if the member variable `actionMethodName` changes.

So if someone knows how to do this in a more future-proof way, please add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is an open @todo in the viewhelper f:form

```
         * @todo filter out referrer information that is equal to the target (e.g. same packageKey)
     */
    protected function renderHiddenReferrerFields()
...
```

My copy&paste-Workaround was to extend the viewhelper f:form. I defined a child-class in my extension.

```
<?php
namespace Porth\Positioner\ViewHelpers;

class FormViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\FormViewHelper {


/**
 * Renders hidden form fields for referrer information about
 * the current controller and action.
 *
 * Renders hidden form field for secured referrer information about the current controller and action.
 *
 * This method is called twice, to deal with subclasses of this class in a most compatible way
 *
 * @param string|null $action
 * @param string|null $controller
 * @param string|null $vendor
 * @param string|null $extension
 *
 * @return string Hidden field with secured referrer information
 * @todo filter out referrer information that is equal to the target (e.g. same packageKey)
 */
protected function renderHiddenReferrerFields($action =null,  $controller = null, $vendor = null, $extension = null )
{
    $request = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
    $extensionName = ((is_null($extension))? $request->getControllerExtensionName() : $extension);
    $vendorName = ((is_null($vendor))? $request->getControllerVendorName() : $vendor);
    $controllerName = ((is_null($controller)) ? $request->getControllerName() : $controller);
    $actionName = ((is_null($action))? $request->getControllerActionName() : $action);
    $result = LF;
    $result .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[@extension]') . '" value="' . $extensionName . '" />' . LF;
    if ($vendorName !== null) {
        $result .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[@vendor]') . '" value="' . $vendorName . '" />' . LF;
    }
    $result .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[@controller]') . '" value="' . $controllerName . '" />' . LF;
    $result .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[@action]') . '" value="' . $actionName . '" />' . LF;
    $result .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[arguments]') . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->hashService->appendHmac(base64_encode(serialize($request->getArguments())))) . '" />' . LF;
    $result .= $this->renderHiddenSecuredReferrerField($actionName,  $controllerName, $vendorName, $extensionName);

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Renders hidden form field for secured referrer information about the current controller and action.
 *
 * This method is called twice, to deal with subclasses of this class in a most compatible way
 *
 * @param string|null $action
 * @param string|null $controller
 * @param string|null $vendor
 * @param string|null $extension
 *
 * @return string Hidden field with secured referrer information
 */
protected function renderHiddenSecuredReferrerField($action = null,  $controller = null, $vendor = null, $extension = null )
{
    if ($this->securedReferrerFieldRendered) {
        return '';
    }
    $request = $this->renderingContext->getControllerContext()->getRequest();
    $extensionName = ((is_null($extension))? $request->getControllerExtensionName() : $extension);
    $vendorName = ((is_null($vendor))? $request->getControllerVendorName() : $vendor);
    $controllerName = ((is_null($controller)) ? $request->getControllerName() : $controller);
    $actionName = ((is_null($action))? $request->getControllerActionName() : $action);
    $actionRequest = [
        '@extension' => $extensionName,
        '@controller' => $controllerName,
        '@action' => $actionName,
    ];
        if ($vendorName !== null) {
        $actionRequest['@vendor'] = $vendorName;
    }
    $result = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->prefixFieldName('__referrer[@request]') . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->hashService->appendHmac(serialize($actionRequest))) . '" />' . LF;
    $this->securedReferrerFieldRendered = true;
    return $result;
}


/**
 * Render the form.
 *
 * @param string $action Target action
 * @param array $arguments Arguments
 * @param string $controller Target controller
 * @param string $vendor Target vendor
 * @param string $extensionName Target Extension Name (without "tx_" prefix and no underscores). If NULL the current extension name is used
 * @param string $pluginName Target plugin. If empty, the current plugin name is used
 * @param int $pageUid Target page uid
 * @param mixed $object Object to use for the form. Use in conjunction with the "property" attribute on the sub tags
 * @param int $pageType Target page type
 * @param bool $noCache set this to disable caching for the target page. You should not need this.
 * @param bool $noCacheHash set this to suppress the cHash query parameter created by TypoLink. You should not need this.
 * @param string $section The anchor to be added to the action URI (only active if $actionUri is not set)
 * @param string $format The requested format (e.g. ".html") of the target page (only active if $actionUri is not set)
 * @param array $additionalParams additional action URI query parameters that won't be prefixed like $arguments (overrule $arguments) (only active if $actionUri is not set)
 * @param bool $absolute If set, an absolute action URI is rendered (only active if $actionUri is not set)
 * @param bool $addQueryString If set, the current query parameters will be kept in the action URI (only active if $actionUri is not set)
 * @param array $argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString arguments to be removed from the action URI. Only active if $addQueryString = TRUE and $actionUri is not set
 * @param string $fieldNamePrefix Prefix that will be added to all field names within this form. If not set the prefix will be tx_yourExtension_plugin
 * @param string $actionUri can be used to overwrite the "action" attribute of the form tag
 * @param string $objectName name of the object that is bound to this form. If this argument is not specified, the name attribute of this form is used to determine the FormObjectName
 * @param string $hiddenFieldClassName
 * @return string rendered form
 */
public function render($action = null, array $arguments = array(), $controller = null, $vendor = null, $extensionName = null, $pluginName = null, $pageUid = null, $object = null, $pageType = 0, $noCache = false, $noCacheHash = false, $section = '', $format = '', array $additionalParams = array(), $absolute = false, $addQueryString = false, array $argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString = array(), $fieldNamePrefix = null, $actionUri = null, $objectName = null, $hiddenFieldClassName = null)
{
    $this->setFormActionUri();
    if (strtolower($this->arguments['method']) === 'get') {
        $this->tag->addAttribute('method', 'get');
    } else {
        $this->tag->addAttribute('method', 'post');
    }
    $this->addFormObjectNameToViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->addFormObjectToViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->addFieldNamePrefixToViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->addFormFieldNamesToViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $formContent = $this->renderChildren();

    if ($this->arguments['hiddenFieldClassName'] !== null) {
        $content = LF . '<div class="' . htmlspecialchars($this->arguments['hiddenFieldClassName']) . '">';
    } else {
        $content = LF . '<div>';
    }

    $content .= $this->renderHiddenIdentityField($this->arguments['object'], $this->getFormObjectName());
    $content .= $this->renderAdditionalIdentityFields();
    $content .= $this->renderHiddenReferrerFields($action ,  $controller , $vendor , $extensionName );
//        $content .= $this->renderHiddenSecuredReferrerField($action ,  $controller , $vendor , $extensionName );

    // Render the trusted list of all properties after everything else has been rendered
    $content .= $this->renderTrustedPropertiesField();

    $content .= LF . '</div>' . LF;
    $content .= $formContent;
    $this->tag->setContent($content);
    $this->removeFieldNamePrefixFromViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->removeFormObjectFromViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->removeFormObjectNameFromViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->removeFormFieldNamesFromViewHelperVariableContainer();
    $this->removeCheckboxFieldNamesFromViewHelperVariableContainer();
    return $this->tag->render();
}
```

}